Fedora 41/RedHat 9.4 crash in check_match
Trying to run a console 32bit application (compiled under Devuan Chimaera 32bit) that uses ncurses but it crashes in Fedora 41/RedHat 9.4.
./myapp: /lib/libtinfo.so.6: no version information available (required by ./myapp)
./myapp: /lib/libncursesw.so.6: no version information available (required by ./myapp)
./myapp: /lib/libncursesw.so.6: no version information available (required by ./myapp)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

The core dump shows:
Debuginfod has been enabled.
To make this setting permanent, add 'set debuginfod enabled on' to .gdbinit.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `./myapp'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0xf7eecde5 in check_match (undef_name=undef_name@entry=0xf7dac13c "__divdi3", ref=ref@entry=0xf7d4aff0, version=version@entry=0xf78dc400, 
    flags=9, type_class=1, sym=0x56628e68, symidx=194, strtab=0x56628ee8 "", map=0xf7f1aa20, versioned_sym=0xffbf8f2c, num_versions=0xffbf8f28)
    at dl-lookup.c:116

warning: 116    dl-lookup.c: No such file or directory
(gdb) bt
#0  0xf7eecde5 in check_match (undef_name=undef_name@entry=0xf7dac13c "__divdi3", ref=ref@entry=0xf7d4aff0, version=version@entry=0xf78dc400, 
    flags=9, type_class=1, sym=0x56628e68, symidx=194, strtab=0x56628ee8 "", map=0xf7f1aa20, versioned_sym=0xffbf8f2c, num_versions=0xffbf8f28)
    at dl-lookup.c:116
#1  0xf7eed239 in do_lookup_x (undef_name=undef_name@entry=0xf7dac13c "__divdi3", new_hash=new_hash@entry=2851089606, 
    old_hash=old_hash@entry=0xffbf8fb0, ref=0xf7d4aff0, result=0xffbf8fb4, scope=0xf7f1ab8c, i=<optimized out>, version=0xf78dc400, flags=9, 
    skip=0x0, type_class=1, undef_map=0xf7edc960) at dl-lookup.c:432
#2  0xf7eeda10 in _dl_lookup_symbol_x (undef_name=0xf7dac13c "__divdi3", undef_map=0xf7edc960, ref=0xffbf907c, symbol_scope=<optimized out>, 
    version=0xf78dc400, type_class=1, flags=9, skip_map=0x0) at dl-lookup.c:792
#3  0xf7ef17d8 in resolve_map (l=<optimized out>, scope=<optimized out>, ref=0xffbf907c, version=0xf78dc400, r_type=7) at dl-reloc.c:190
#4  elf_machine_rel (map=0xf7edc960, scope=<optimized out>, reloc=0xf7dba28c, sym=0xf7d4aff0, version=0xf78dc400, 
    reloc_addr_arg=0xf7e568c0 <__divdi3@got.plt>, skip_ifunc=<optimized out>) at ../sysdeps/i386/dl-machine.h:264
#5  elf_dynamic_do_Rel (map=0xf7edc960, scope=<optimized out>, reladdr=<optimized out>, relsize=<optimized out>, nrelative=<optimized out>, 
    lazy=<optimized out>, skip_ifunc=<optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/glibc-2.40-3.fc41.i386/elf/do-rel.h:147
#6  _dl_relocate_object (l=<optimized out>, scope=<optimized out>, reloc_mode=<optimized out>, consider_profiling=<optimized out>)
    at dl-reloc.c:301
#7  0xf7f02353 in dl_main (phdr=<optimized out>, phnum=<optimized out>, user_entry=<optimized out>, auxv=<optimized out>) at rtld.c:2314
#8  0xf7efe845 in _dl_sysdep_start (start_argptr=0xffbf9480, dl_main=0xf7f00440 <dl_main>) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/dl-sysdep.c:141
#9  0xf7f00207 in _dl_start_final (arg=0xffbf9480) at rtld.c:494
#10 _dl_start (arg=<optimized out>) at rtld.c:581
#11 0xf7efefab in _start () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
(gdb) 

I have another 32-bit console app compiled in same environment that gives the message about no version information but runs okay after that:
./myapp2: /lib/libtinfo.so.6: no version information available (required by ./myapp2)
./myapp2: /lib/libncursesw.so.6: no version information available (required by ./myapp2)
./myapp2: /lib/libncursesw.so.6: no version information available (required by ./myapp2)

What might this be? How is it fixed?

Fedora 41 doesn't have the libraries to match (and packagers are unwilling to fix that problem).  You'll have to recompile.

@ThomasDickey do you know why one app runs and the other crashes (is it related to no version info) ?    Also if I recompile, are you saying to compile under fedora 32bit ?   Doesn't seem like you should have to recompile an app just to run on different linux distros.

The Devuan executable was linked to ncurses which was built to supply versioned symbols, while the Fedora libraries do not provide that information.  The runtime loader should be friendlier, but that's the problem.
